# Динамический линейный граф на Flutter

Tags: диаграммы, graph, dart, flutter

Всем привет! Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Мы от сервера каждую секунду получаем точки, нужно отобразить их красиво на графике, хочу использовать flutter_chart от Гугл, но не понимаю как сделать динамические данные, а не перестраивать виджет каждый раз? Как сделать анимированные добавление точки и удаление самой старой? График должен выглядеть так, будто он плавно ползет. Или может есть другие библиотеки, которые это умеют?

Comment: Сделаете асинхронную перерисовку виджета с графиком, которая будет вызываться при получение новых данных.
Либо посмотрите на [fcharts](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fcharts)

Comment: fcharts вел себя странно при удалении точки с конца. Решил вопрос с помощью поворота flutter_charts от Google и изготовления кастомных легенд и осей